# Need assistance for homemade dc motor

Tags: dc-motor

I have made a dc motor with two coils and 4 commutators with 2 brushes. 
It has been powered by a 12v 1.5amp adapter and the coils have been wrapped 40 times on each end.
However when I turn the power on it does not spin and goes back and forth or just vibrates. Can anyone help/tell me what I have done wrong?[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have the commutator contacts at the wrong angle relative to the windings.

Comment: I suggest you add a diagram of the construction including the angles between windings, commutators and brushes, and a wiring diagram.

Comment: And are you using a DC motor? Hit the edit link under your question and add in all the information.

Answer (score 0):

The brushes should be energising the windings that point perpendicular to the magnets.
rotate the motor slowly and observe the angle each coil will be energised at then move the magnets or brushes to compensate.

the coils should be polarised the same check that the current flows consistently clockwise (or anticlockwuise) when viewed from above for each coils facing up. and that it flows parallel in th same directions in the coil below it

Make sure that you are not over-loading your power supply. put a 8 ohm (or greater) resistor in series with the motor, use a buck converter with input current limiting, or use dry-cell batteries instead.